# glassfish 3.1.2 admin console port 4848 blocked by firewall

Tags: apache-2.2, console, glassfish

I've got a remote server. There is glassfish 3.1.2 running behind apache 2.2. The administration port 4848 is blocked by firewall so that I cannot use http://some_server.com:4848 where some_server is the domain name of my server. How can I configure apache and glassfish in order to be able to access glassfish administration console?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: For port-forwarding using putty: [http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html](http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have SSH access to your server you can forward this port to your local machine like this: `ssh -L 4848:127.0.0.1:4848 user@some_server.com` and then use `http://127.0.0.1:4848` on your local PC to access Glassfish admin interface.

Comment: Thanks, for you answer. What ssh client would you recommend for doing that?

Comment: The command above is valid for a command line SSH client, you can install it on Windows using Cygwin suite. You can also use PuTTY but port forwarding in PuTTY should be configured differently. PuTTY uses a graphical menu to configure such things.

Comment: Do you know anything about accessing glassfish admin console through apache using mod_proxy or mod_jk?

Comment: No, I've never tried it